# collection defaultdict with multiple keys

Tags: python, csv, collections, defaultdict

im using collection defaultdict to read a huge CSV file in python. I have the csv header something like that:

```
main_id, id1, value_x, id2, id3, id4, value_y, value_z, value0
```

Im able to read the file line by line and use `main_id` as the default key. Is it possible to use multiple keys so that the dictionary would be like `dict[main_id,id1,id2,id3,id4]` ?

Comment: Yes. Why do you ask? Did you try it and it didn't work? What did you try? `dict[main_id,id1,id2,id3,id4]` is perfectly valid syntax (although you should never use `dict` as a variable name).

Answer (score 1):

Use a `tuple` of the elements. So you will have

```
data = dict()
data[(main_id,id1,id2,id3,id4)]
```

or simply

```
data = dict()
data[main_id,id1,id2,id3,id4]  # defaults to a tuple
```

which is exactly what you were trying to do.

Comment: The parentheses are unnecessary, so this answer doesn't actually add anything to the question...and `dict` is still a horrible name for a variable.

Comment: I've modified the answer a bit since `dict` is a _really_ bad variable name

Comment: Sure. Most people don't realize that it's the comma, not the parentheses, that builds a `tuple`.